# Convert MIDI file to audio file using an SF2 soundfont library with audiokit

Tags: ios, xcode, audiokit

Is it possible to convert a MIDI file to an audio file (e.g. MP3) using "audiokit" for iOS and an existing soundfont library (SF2)? Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. Use AKMIDI, AKMIDISampler, loadSoundFont, and renderToFile to make this happen.

http://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKMIDI.html

http://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKSampler.html

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Playback/Sampler/AKSampler%2BSoundFont.swift#L33

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/develop/AudioKit/Common/Internals/AudioKit.swift#L558